# Flutter: how can I make a rounded PopupMenuButton's InkWell?

Tags: flutter

I have a PopupMenuButton inside a FloatingActionButton. But it's InkWell is not rounded, it is standard square shape. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Actually, looking at your question again, it seems like you are trying to use the `PopupMenuButton` in a way it was not made for. You are not supposed to nest buttons. Instead, I recommend you to copy the source code of `PopupMenuButton` and to base it on a FAB instead of an `IconButton`.

Answer (score 55):

Use `customBorder` property of `InkWell`:

```
InkWell(
    customBorder: CircleBorder(),
    onTap: () {}
    child: ...
)
```

Comment: The Inkwell I am talking about is the one used by the PopupMenuButton itself

Answer (score 23):

You can use `borderRadius` property of `InkWell` to get a rounded Ink Splash.

```
Material(
 color: Colors.lightBlue,
 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
 child: InkWell(
  splashColor: Colors.blue,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
  child: Text('Button'),
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the InkWell's shape to rounded from standard square shape, Material's borderRadius property is used. Example code is given below -

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: InkWell(
                child: PopupMenuButton(
                  //shape is used to change the shape of popup card 
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: Icon(Icons.mode_edit, size: 22.0, color: Colors.red,),
                  itemBuilder: (context) => [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Child 1"),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Child 2"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It's working with: ```shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0))```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where the child of the PopupMenuButton would have a square InkWell around it.

In order to make it behave like an IconButton, which naturally uses the rounded InkWell, I simply had to use the icon paramater instead of the child.

```
icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
```

This is indicated in the documentation for that paramater:

```
  /// If provided, the [icon] is used for this button
  /// and the button will behave like an [IconButton].
  final Widget icon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Inkwell with Material. Add Border Radius

```
Material(
                
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( // add
                  Radius.circular(20) 
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Ink(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      "Kayıt Ol",
                      
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: cKutuRengi,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Here's how to make the tap effect look right

```
Material(
                
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20)
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  customBorder:RoundedRectangleBorder( // add
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(20)
                    )
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint("on tap");
                  },
                  child: Ink(
                    
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      "Kayıt Ol",
                      
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: cKutuRengi,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are not using PopupMenuButton like the question specified. If you're simply using an icon child then you can use the icon property rather than child as already explained above, but if you want rounded corners on some other child, you wrap it with a Material, and wrap that with a ClipRRect [See this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484300/correct-ripple-effect-shape-for-circular-icon-popup-menu)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the child of PopUpMenuButton to have border radius you can do like this.

```
return ClipRRect(
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
      child: Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: PopupMenuButton(),
     )
);
```

This piece of code will help you to have a bordered radius inkwell. This solution has already mentioned in the official Flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html#:%7E:text=InkWell%20isn%27t%20clipping%20properly&text=An%20easy%20solution%20is%20to,See%20Ink%20for%20an%20example.).