# Correct ripple effect shape for circular icon popup menu

Tags: flutter, material-design, popupmenu

In Flutter, I'm wanting to style icon buttons with a circular border, and also have the Material ripple effect work correctly so that the ripple effect is contained with the circle. In the following code, the first button works correctly. In the second (popup) button, the ripple effect extends out to a square that surrounds the button, rather than being constrained to the circular border.

[image: The second button]

```
MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: MaterialButton(
              minWidth: 0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
                child: Icon(Icons.home, size: 27.0),
              ),
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            onSelected: (String action) {},
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
                child: Icon(Icons.menu, size: 27.0),
              ),
            ),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
              PopupMenuItem<String>(child: ListTile(title: Text('Log Out'))),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is there a way to get the popup button working correctly?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `PopupMenuButton` with a `ClipRRect`?

Comment: @Ovidiu I tried `ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24), child: PopupMenuButton(...))`, but it unfortunately didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `ClipRRect` as well as `Material`:

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
    ...
```

`PopupMenuButton` wraps the `child` with an `InkWell`, which for some reason is not clipped unless also wrapped within `Material`.